# What's the proper expression for "An approach to a problem"?

Tags: synonyms

I want to express the following:

Method X provides a way to tackle problem Y.

Is there a neater way of expressing this?

Comment: Solution? Why not that?

Comment: Define *proper*. Define *neater*.

Comment: @Drew Is there a term for responding with "define [word]" to show that the question asked is kind of weird?

Comment: @Drew I guess proper + neater = shorter

Comment: @NVZ: Would "POB" be what you're looking for?

Comment: @WeaponX: *Shorter* is good - operational, easily measurable. *Proper* and *neater* are,  in our context, (typically) primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @Drew No. I've seen in a lot of movies. A person asks something awkward. The other person replies with "define (word)" because they're unable to answer it clearly, not only because the question is awkward. Is there a name for such response? Maybe I'll ask in chat later.

Comment: @NVZ: "Not *only* because" suggests that the question is awkward, at least. And that can often mean that it is not easy to answer. Anyway, instead of awkward, here, I'd say underspecified, so unclear. And when something is underspecified it is *often* difficult to answer clearly. To put it another way: GIGO.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps *[addresses](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/address)*?

> to treat of; deal with: *chapter 10 addresses the problem of transitivity*

*Collins*

So

> *Method X addresses problem Y*

Answer (score 0):

What about [handles](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/handle): *to deal with or treat in a particular way*

> Method X handles problem Y.